# AngularJs2 - ng2-map not working/showing up

Tags: google-maps, angular2-directives

As I was working on a homepage where I really need a simple map like google maps in my angular2 app. Nothing shows up where there should be a map. Sure I'm just missing something.

Under is my System.config

```
<!-- Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'ng2-map': {
                main: 'index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
        map: {
            'ng2-map': 'node_modules/ng2-map'
        }
    });
    System.import('app/js/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

And then there's the Component trying to use the map directive.

```
import { NG2_MAP_DIRECTIVES } from "ng2-map";

@Component({
    selector: 'contact',
    templateUrl: '../../../html/contact.html',
    directives: [NG2_MAP_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

And finally the html part:

```
<div class="ContentRow-Paralax" id="secondAbout">
<div class="topstripe">
</div>
<div class="stripe">
    <h2>Trollolol</h2>
</div>
```

```
<div class="ContentRow-Paralax">
<ng2-map id="map" [center]="[40.74, -74.18]" default-style="false"></ng2-map>
```

There is not much else going on I think, and there's no error logs to tell me where I went wrong. Hope you can help me out! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to define default markers or set some css on the map container. My maps wouldn't show until I did this.